# Can I batch update participant role for an event for all contacts registered for an event who have a certain tag?

Tags: civievent, search, batches

The scenario is this:
I have an event -- we'll call it "Meeting." There are 200 contacts registered for "Meeting." All 100 have the participant role "attendee." 60 of the contacts who are registered for "meeting" are tagged as "meeting speaker." I would like to batch update so that all 60 contacts with the "meeting speaker" tag have their participant role switched to "speaker" instead of "attendee."

If I do a contact search, I can isolate the tagged participants, but not update their participant roles. It won't let me add them to the event as they are already registered.

On the other hand, if I do a participant search I can batch update registration status, but not search only registrants who have the tag.

Am I missing something or is this just not doable? I'd really rather not manually change all 60 statuses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable with Advanced Search.  You can enter your criteria (the tag) and change the Display Results As field to read "Event Participants", and then click Search.  The results will be the folks tagged Meeting Speaker, but your Actions on the result screen will be geared toward Event type actions.

More info on the Display Results As option can be found on this [CiviCRM blog post](https://civicrm.org/blog/michael-mcandrew/tip-making-the-most-of-display-results-as-in-advanced-search).

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize this was possible.

Comment: @jbc63 you bet! If this worked for you, please mark the answer as correct (click the check mark).